# Solve the double integral of $e^{x/y}dydx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I am asked to solve the double integral
$$\int_0^3 \int_{x}^3 e^{x/y} dy dx$$

I have tried doing it through "u-sub" and integration by parts, however, I cannot seem to solve it. I have also tried polar coordinates and have had no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Use Fubini's Theorem and change integration order:

$$\int_0^3\int_x^3 e^{x/y}dydx=\int_0^3\int_0^y e^{x/y}dxdy=\left.\int_0^3y e^{x/y}dy\right|_0^y=\int_0^3y(e-1)=$$

$$=\left.\frac{e-1}2y^2\right|_0^3=\frac{9(e-1)}2$$

Comment: Perhaps keep the $dy$ for the single integrals.

Comment: @GEdgar Of course, omission. Thank you, editing now.

Comment: why are the bounds then changed from x to 3 to 0 to y?

Comment: @BennettLerud In the original integral: when $\;x\;$ ranges from zero to $\;3\;$ , $\;y\;$ goes from the line $\;x\;$ to 3. This means $\;y\;$ goes from zero to three (draw the graphs!), while $\;x\;$ goes from zero to $\;y\;$